# When using "Async", why "Await" is used

Tags: asynchronous, android-asynctask, async-await, synchronization

We use the term "Async" to allow the code stream to continue without blocking the main stream. This is OK. We want the mainstream to continue without waiting for that process to complete. But usually, "Async and Await" are used together.

My question is; When we add "await", we expect "Async" status in the code stream. In this case, I do not understand what is the benefit of using "Async"? Can someone explain this, thank you, good work.

Comment: These link help you to understand the async/await [link](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which technology you're referring to. I'll assume you're referring to the `async` and `await` keywords that have been added to many languages the last few years.

In that case, this statement is actually incorrect:

> We use the term "Async" to allow the code stream to continue without blocking the main stream.

In C#, JavaScript, Python, F#, and Visual Basic, the `async` keyword does *not* act asynchronously. It has two effects:

1. Enable the `await` keyword within that method/lambda.
2. Transform that method/lambda into a state machine.

So `async` does *not* mean "run this code on a background thread" or anything like that, which is a common but incorrect assumption.

The first point above is important for backwards compatibility. Each of these languages use `await` as a contextual keyword, so the text "await" in a program is only a keyword if it is in a method marked with `async`. This allows the languages to introduce the new keywords without breaking any existing code (e.g., someone's code that used `await` as a variable name).

See [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html) of mine which collected a lot of the discussion around the keywords as they were originally designed for C#/VB. Those same design decisions carried over almost exactly to other languages as they adopted the keywords, too. One of the resources linked from that post is [Eric Lippert's post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/) on why we need an `async` keyword in addition to an `await` keyword.

Comment: Though this answer is of course correct, I note that the fact that the method is transformed into a state machine is an implementation detail; implementers of the specification are free to make other transformations as long as the semantics are maintained. The way I prefer to think of it is that the method becomes a *coroutine*: a method that is capable of being cooperatively suspended and resumed. Building a state machine is just a particularly handy way to implement coroutine semantics.